# node.js - http request with status 200 but no response data?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

hello i have a mongoose database and i want to retrieve data based on the account id, im using a middleware to verify the account which provides the id, the response http method is 200 but i receive no data on postman.

```
async function getAccountDetails(authAccount) {
  try {
    const accId = authAccount._id;

    const account = await Users.findById({ _id: accId });
    console.log(account);

    return account;
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}

/**

router.get(
  "/list",
  authMiddleware,
  async function _getallUsersByAccount(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const data = await getAccountDetails(req.authAccount);

      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("no bot");
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: res.json() is preferable for transmission data between the frontend and backend

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting to send your response back.

Somewhere in your router.get function you need to return data.

Try this:

```
router.get(
  "/list",
  authMiddleware,
  async function _getallUsersByAccount(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const data = await getAccountDetails(req.authAccount);

      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("no bot");
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```

I've added res.send(data) after the console.log(data).

Comment: res.json() is preferable for transmission data between the frontend and backend

Comment: @NishangRaiyani - `res.send()` auto detects that the data is a Javascript object and automatically serializes it into JSON.  There is no need to separately call `res.json()` so it just becomes a personal style which you use - no particularly right or wrong way.

Comment: i fixed the issue by rearranging the routes order. there were two get requests under each other, when i reversed them it worked